# Converting Lisp macros to Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Hey everyone so I'm looking for a way to convert a lisp macro to work in Clojure I looked at some other posts talking about if you could convert but they really didn't show an example and was maybe looking for some help on this.

```
(defmacro n-of (n form) 
  (let ((lst-sym (gensym)) 
        (i-sym (gensym))) 
    `(let ((,lst-sym ())) 
       (dotimes (,i-sym ,n) 
         (push ,form ,lst-sym)) 
       (nreverse ,lst-sym))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lisp macro i assume Common Lisp macro.

```
(defmacro n-of [n & form]
  `(let [f# #(do ~@form)]
     (take ~n (repeatedly f#))))
```

where the & is like &rest or &body. #() is (lambda...). ~@ is ,@-. '~' is ','.

Comment: ...and the f# nicely saves us having to invoke gensym.

Comment: If we go with the original in which the form is a single sexpr, could we do?:

    (defmacro n-of [n form]
        `(take ~n (repeatedly ~form)))